# How to show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n\ln(n)}$ is divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

As the title of this question states, how should I show $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty   \frac{1}{1+n \ln(n)}$$ is divergent?

I'm thinking of using comparison test but cannot figure out an upper bound $g(n)$ for $$1+n\ln(n)$$ such that $\sum \frac{1}{g(n)}$ diverges.

I thought about using integral test but I think integrating  $\frac{1}{1+n \ln(n)}$ is tedious...

Ratio test also does not seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use the comparison test with the series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n\log n},$$which diverges, by the integral test.

Answer (score 2):

By comparison test $\sum \frac 1{ 1+n\ln n}$ is convergent iff $\sum \frac 1{ n\ln n}$ is convergent. Now use  the integral test.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative by [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) consider

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  2^na_{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty   \frac{2^n}{1+2^n \ln(2^n)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty   \frac{2^n}{1+n\cdot 2^n \ln 2}$$

which diverges by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1n$, indeed

$$\frac{\frac{2^n}{1+n\cdot 2^n \ln 2}}{\frac1n}=\frac{n\cdot2^n}{1+n\cdot 2^n \ln 2}\to \frac1{\ln 2}$$

Comment: Should be $1+2^n\ln(2^n)$ in the denominator.

Comment: @Milten of course! Thanks